# pip not working on Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, python, pip, macos-mojave

When I try to use pip commands on Mac Mojave, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 19.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==19.1.1'))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==19.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you upgrade pip? What command did you run?

Comment: i think yes but this before month and i think there was two versions of python on my machine and i think i updated one of these versions

Comment: Please post the exact `pip` command that you use, `pip --version` and the `requirements.txt` of your Python project

Comment: Mods, I think this belongs to StackOverflow, or possible apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try using `pip3` command

Answer (score 0):

Without sufficient details on your Python project, your pip version and actual command, I can only infer that the error message happens because your Python project explicitly request for `pip 19.1.2`. For example, [your requirements.txt file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files) may have

```
pip=19.1.2
```

### Use looser version dependency

You can change the requirements to

```
pip>=19.1.0,<=20.0
```

### Upgrade pip

Upgrade pip to the latest version

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```